# SDL + C++ Error: LNK2019 unresolved external symbol_SDL_main referencedin function

Tags: sdl, sdl-2, lnk2019

I Google-d this problem and viewed at least 20 threads about this and tried different solutons but none worked out.This code is in SDL 2.0.3 in Visual Studio 2013 Express. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_mixer.h>

class MGGMain{

int player_x;
int player_y;
int player_w = 50;
int player_h = 50;

SDL_Rect player_rect;
SDL_Texture* player_text;

SDL_Window* window;
SDL_Renderer* renderer;
SDL_Event* mainEvent;

bool quit;

void Init()
{

}

void LoadAssets(SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    //IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, <path>);
    player_text = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "images/dev/dev_player");
}

void Update()
{
    int player_x;
    int player_y;
    SDL_Rect player_rect = CreateRect(player_h, player_w, player_x, player_y);

    if (mainEvent->type == SDL_QUIT)
    {
        quit = true;
    }
}

void Draw(SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    //SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, <texture>, <rect>)
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, player_text, &player_rect, &player_rect);
}

SDL_Rect CreateRect(int h, int w, int x, int y)
{
    SDL_Rect rect;
    rect.x = x;
    rect.y = y;
    rect.h = h;
    rect.w = w;
    return rect;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Initialyzing SDL..." << std::endl;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    std::cout << "All initialyzed, creating window and event system..." << std::endl;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("MGG", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 1200, 700, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    std::cout << "All succeded!" << std::endl;
    quit = false;
    if (window = NULL){
        std::cout << "SDL Error: Window couldn't be created!" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    std::cout << "Creating renderer..." << std::endl;
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    std::cout << "Renderer creation success, beginning main loop." << std::endl;
    mainEvent = new SDL_Event();
    LoadAssets(renderer);
    Init();
    while (!quit)
    {
        SDL_PollEvent(mainEvent);
        Update();
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        Draw(renderer);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    delete mainEvent;

    return 0;
}



};
```

Comment: What's the actual problem?

Comment: You need to add sdlmain.lib to your linker input list

Comment: The problem is it is giving me an error when building the project.

Comment: I already added sdl2main.lib to the linker input list, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: remove `};` that comes after `return 0; } `

Answer (score 0):

Your program has no main() function.

The main function in your code is inside class MGGMain, so it becomes MGGMain::main(). It needs to be simply main(), in the highest scope, that is, outside any classes or the compiler will not find it.

SDL errors out because it overrides the main used by SDL programs to do some initializations and then calls the real main(), but since there is no main(), it throws unresolved external symbol error.